# how to get form name using Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, forms

I am working with asp c#, and I try to use the form name as an id getter

```
 Response.Write("<td><form runnat=\"server\" name=\"formCon" + mb.IdMbl + "\" action=\"../General/CurrentBlog.aspx\">");
                   Response.Write("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"consultar\">");   
                   Response.Write("</form></td>");
```

in the next page I want to get the form name using Request.Form but I dont know how

Comment: All the code is within the <script runat="server">    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}

Answer (score 0):

A bit more context would be needed to answer correctly here:

Is this webforms? If so, there could be only one form on the page and I don't see a purpose of getting it's name in the first place.

May be try like this:

```
var form = Document.GetControlById("formCon");
var name = form.Name;
```

Comment: his form name is not formCon it is "formCon" + mb.IdMbl . thats why he wants to get it. please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Reread, and sounds to me that the code in OPs post is what writes the form on the page. So my statement should still hold true.

Answer (score 0):

You can Store your form name in some hidden variable and get.

Example:

**Set :**

```
Request.Form["formname"]=\"formCon" + mb.IdMbl + "\";
```

**Get :**

```
var myformName= Request.Form["formname"];
```